# Android : how to extract audio samples from downloading audio file with MediaExtractor

Tags: android, audio-streaming, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I'm making a very simple music app, and I try to figure out how to do this:

- download an audio file and record the file locally
- ***at any moment***, extract the audio frames from the file (during or after the download)

**1)** For the downloading part, I use Retrofit following [this example](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/05/downloading-file-using-retrofit.html). To make it short, it allows me to download a file, and recording it locally while it's downloading (so I don't have to wait for the end of the download to access the data of the file).

**2)** For the frame extracting part, I use `MediaExtractor` and `MediaCodec` like this:

```
MediaCodec codec;
MediaExtractor extractor;

MediaFormat format;
ByteBuffer[] codecInputBuffers;
ByteBuffer[] codecOutputBuffers;
Boolean sawInputEOS = false;
Boolean sawOutputEOS = false;
AudioTrack mAudioTrack;
MediaCodec.BufferInfo info;

File outputFile = null;
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   // the file being downloaded:
   outputFile = new File(directory, "test.mp3");
   try {
      FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(outputFile);
      fileDescriptor = fileInputStream.getFD();
   }
   catch (Exception e) {}
}

// Called once when enough data to extract.
private void onAudioFileReady() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // thread :
            Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO);

            // audio :
            extractor = new MediaExtractor();

            // the extractor only extracts the already downloaded part of the file:
            try {
                //  extractor.setDataSource(url);
                //  extractor.setDataSource(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
                //  extractor.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(outputFile.getAbsolutePath()), null);
                extractor.setDataSource(fileDescriptor);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {}

            format = extractor.getTrackFormat(0);
            String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
            int sampleRate = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE);

            try {
                codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {}
            codec.configure(format, null, null, 0);
            codec.start();

            codecInputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();
            codecOutputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();

            extractor.selectTrack(0);

            int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(
                    sampleRate,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    sampleRate,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    minBufferSize,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM
            );
            info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            mAudioTrack.play();

            do {
                input();
                output();
            }
            while (!sawInputEOS);
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}

private void input() {
    int inputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
    if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = codecInputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
        int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(byteBuffer, 0);
        long presentationTimeUs = 0;

        if (sampleSize < 0) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Saw input end of stream!");
            sampleSize = 0;
        }
        else {
            presentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime();
        }

        codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex,
                0,
                sampleSize,
                presentationTimeUs,
                sawInputEOS ? MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM : 0);

        // doesn't seem to work:
        extractor.advance();
    }
}

private void output() {
    final int res = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, -1);
    if (res >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer buf = codecOutputBuffers[res];

        final byte[] chunk = new byte[info.size];
        buf.get(chunk);
        buf.clear();

        if (chunk.length > 0) {
            mAudioTrack.write(chunk, 0, chunk.length);
        }
        codec.releaseOutputBuffer(res, false);

        if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
            sawOutputEOS = true;
        }
    }
    else if (res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
        codecOutputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();
    }
    else if (res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
        final MediaFormat oformat = codec.getOutputFormat();
        mAudioTrack.setPlaybackRate(oformat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE));
    }
}
```

**What it does:**

When `onAudioFileReady()` is called, this code extracts and plays the audio samples of the file, *but only the ones that have already been downloaded*. When it reaches the end of the already downloaded part, the `MediaExtractor` stops (it looks like `extractor.advance()` doesn't want to continue the extraction...), even if there is more data available...

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to be able to continue the extraction of the audio samples of the file, as long as there is enough data for it of course.

**IMPORTANT:**

At that point, you may ask why I don't just use `extractor.setDataSource(url)`. Here are the reasons why:

- I want to save the audio file locally, so I can play it later
- I want to be able to play the song, even long after the beginning of the download

Does anyone know how to achieve that? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can create a file using the frames you get from MediaExtractor. (Using MediaMuxer for example)

Comment: Thank you but the problem is that MediaExtractor just extracts a small part of my file. I actually don't think I can achieve what I want with this technic, ExoPlayer seems a much better option (but I still don't know how to do it).